# How do I include System.Windows.Shapes?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2008, shapes

I am using Visual Studio 2008 with the .NET Framework (v3.5). I cannot seem to use System.Windows.Shapes, or anything System.Windows.* besides Forms.

Here is the link to the class description:

[System.Windows.Shapes (MSDN Library)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.aspx)

Is there some special thing I need to do to use it?

I checked in all of the framework folders, and the only dll/xml files I have for System.Windows is System.Windows.Forms.

What do I need to do to get this to work?

Comment: Shapes is a WPF library, if you have forms available but not shapes then you are probably using a Winforms project, while it is possible for import the WPF libraries into winforms you will probably not be able to use them as you expect

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This class is part of WPF, from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.shape.aspx):

> Shape Class
>
> Assembly: PresentationFramework (in presentationframework.dll)

Answer (score 8):

You need to add a reference to the PresentationFramework library.

In VisualStudio, right click on your project in the "Solution Explorer". Select "Add Reference". The "PresentationFramework" library will be under the ".NET" tab. You may also need to add "PresentationCore" and "WindowsBase".

You can see your project's current library references by going to the "Solution Explorer" and expanding the "References" item.

Answer (score 3):

You may need to add a reference to the library, <strike>probably System.Windows.Presentation</strike>

Edit: It is in the **PresentationFramework** library

Answer (score 2):

1. Add reference to PresentationFramework from .Net tab
2. write using System.Windows.Shapes

and you are done!

Answer (score 2):

Other solution that works in .Net 4.0:
Go to referenes->add reference and choose PrsentationFramework under .NET tab.