# Including system.windows.shapes, can't find presentationframework.dll

Tags: c#, .net

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and trying to use the Line class in System.Windows.Shapes.

Via [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576622/how-do-i-include-system-windows-shapes) link I found out how it should be done (using the presentationframework.dll), but I can't find it anywhere. When I click References > add reference > .NET, it says

> Filtered to .NET Framework 2.0

So I thought that I didn't have the up to date framework, but even after installing [.NET framework 4.5](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653), it still says that it is somehow filtered...

There must be a really simple solution that I'm not seeing, right?

Comment: What's the target framework of your assembly? Just installing 4.5 doesn't mean your project automatically is using it. You need to set it (different locations in a vb project versus a c# project--believe it's on the compiler tab for c# versus the main project tab for vb)

Comment: That did it. Changed the target framework in the project preferences to 3.5 and now it works.
Thank you so much! I knew it was something simple...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the target framework of your project. Just because you install the framework doesn't mean your project is automatically using it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete the references and add it again, check whether your project is using the same framework version.

You can download from  [`Microsoft .NET Framework 4`](http://www.microsoft.com/de-at/download/details.aspx?id=17718)